# Computer Account cannot login as SYSADMIN

Tags: sql-server

Computer account is not able to login to SQL Server 2017 Express on the same machine. We are getting an error on connection stating that the login failed due to not being able to open the specified database. The database exists and is query-able, the computer account has SYSADMIN role and is also mapped directly to the database.

We've tried using different connection strings, different bitnesses, different accounts(LocalServer, NetworkService, ...), different processes, different databases and different database roles. All network protocols are enabled too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Really just need this to work with the computer account. We can't create a domain account or local windows account (which does work when tested). This usually works just fine but something is amiss.

Comment: Create a SQL Server Account ? Check this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74061/sql-server-2012-cant-log-in-with-machine-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer account never signs in locally.  It's a limitation of the error message that it appears that it's the computer account connecting, as it's kind of a reverse-lookup of the account attempting the connection.

You need to create a login for the local account actually attempting the connection, which will be something like :

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS
```

or

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService] FROM WINDOWS
```

Comment: Bingo! We added [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] and much success.Thank you.